# Kafka Transaction Manager sends to Kafka Broker despite transaction rolling back

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-transactions

My Kafka Producer keeps sending to Kafka Broker despite transaction failing. I have a custom listener i.e. I am not using the @KafkaListener annotation. This is running on Spring-kafka 2.2.x

Any ideas why the message ends up in Kafka despite KafkaTransactionManager rolling back? Here is my setup below:

```
// Kafka producer sender
@Transactional(transactionManager = "kafkaTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void sendToKafkaWithTransaction(final String topic, final Object payload){
    ProducerRecord<String, Object> record = new ProducerRecord(topic, key, payload);
    template.executeInTransaction(kt -> kt.send(record));
}

// RabbitMQ producer sender
@Transactional(transactionManager = "rabbitTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void sendToRabbitmqWithTransaction(final String topic, final String header, final Object payload){
    template.convertAndSend(topic, header, payload);
}

// Chained Transaction Manager
@Bean(name = "chainedKafkaTransactionManager")
public ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<Object, Object> chainedKafkaTransactionManager(
       @Qualifier(value = "transactionalKafkaProducer") ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory,
       @Qualifier(value = "transactionManager") JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager,
       @Qualifier(value = "rabbitTransactionManager") RabbitTransactionManager rabbitTransactionManager) {
   KafkaTransactionManager producerKtm = new KafkaTransactionManager(producerFactory);
producerKtm.setTransactionSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION);
   return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<>(jpaTransactionManager, producerKtm, rabbitTransactionManager);
}


// Listener config
listenerFactory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(chainedKafkaTransactionManager);



// Listener
@Transactional(transactionManager = "chainedKafkaTransactionManager")
public void onMessage(final ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment acknowledgment, Consumer<?, ?> consumer){
    
    try {
            RetryState retryState = new DefaultRetryState(consumerRecord.topic() + "-" + consumerRecord.partition() + "-" + consumerRecord.offset());

            retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
                saveToDb() // This rolls back
                sendToKafkaWithTransaction(topic, payload); // This message gets to Kafa, it should not.
                sendToRabbitmqWithTransaction(topic, payload);  // This rolls back
                throw new Exception("Out of Anger");
                return null;
            }, recoveryCallBack, retryState);

            acknowledgment.acknowledge();
      }
      catch (ListenerExecutionFailedException e) {
         throw e;
      }
}    

// See logs
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Setting JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(104745239<open>)] rollback-only
```

**EDIT:**
Adding spring boot config:

```
spring.kafka:
  admin:
    bootstrap-servers: ${kakfa.host}
  consumer:
    group-id: test-consumers
    client-id: test-consumers
    auto-offset-reset: latest
    value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    enable-auto-commit: false
    properties:
        isolation-level: read_committed
  producer:
    client-id: test-producer
    acks: all
    retries: 3
    transaction-id-prefix: test-producer-tx-
    value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    properties:
      enable.idempotence: true
      transactional.id: tran-id-1-
      max.in.flight.requests.per.connection: 5
      isolation-level: read_committed
```

Edit
More Logs

```
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush]
[ consumer-0-C-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@18061927] for key [public abstract java.lang.Object org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository.saveAndFlush(java.lang.Object)] from thread [consumer-0-C-1]
[ consumer-0-C-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaResourceHolder@23b172f4] for key [org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory@4df8f4e9] bound to thread [consumer-0-C-1]
[ consumer-0-C-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaResourceHolder@23b172f4] for key [org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory@4df8f4e9] bound to thread [consumer-0-C-1]
[ consumer-0-C-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaResourceHolder@23b172f4] for key [org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory@4df8f4e9] bound to thread [consumer-0-C-1]
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate             : Sending: ProducerRecord(topic=topic-1, partition=null)
[-27cf188e6c23-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : Cluster ID: r3baK471R6mIft7L_DIOIg
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate             : Sent: ProducerRecord(topic=topic-1, partition=null)
[ consumer-0-C-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@16bfeffa] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@30eed725] bound to thread [consumer-0-C-1]
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(23309560<open>)] for JPA transaction
[ consumer-0-C-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@cbfb10d] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] bound to thread [consumer-0-C-1]
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Participating in existing transaction
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [com.arca.framework.messaging.services.impl.BoradcastMessageServiceImpl.sendTransactional]
[-27cf188e6c23-1] o.s.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate             : Sent ok: ProducerRecord(topic=topic-1, partition=null), metadata: topic-1-0@185
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,4)
[ consumer-0-C-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitResourceHolder@2655e199] for key [CachingConnectionFactory [channelCacheSize=25, host=localhost, port=5672, active=true rabbitConnectionFactory]] to thread [consumer-0-C-1]
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate      : Executing callback RabbitTemplate$$Lambda$1237/634386320 on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,4), conn: Proxy@3c964873 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@5d9ccad2 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 64338]
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate      : Publishing message (Body:'{ }')
[ consumer-0-C-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitResourceHolder@2655e199] for key [CachingConnectionFactory [channelCacheSize=25, host=localhost, port=5672, active=true rabbitConnectionFactory]] bound to thread [consumer-0-C-1]
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [messaging.services.impl.RabbitMessageServiceImpl.send]
[ consumer-0-C-1] c.a.f.m.k.r.KafkaSingleDispatchReceiver  : Unable to process messages of type: [class messaging.kafka.events.acquiringtmstransaction.TmsTransactionEvent] and id: [92dccb48-2cd2-47b8-b778-8550dcd72d04]
[ consumer-0-C-1] .a.f.m.k.c.KafkaTransactionalRetryPolicy : Retry count [1] for message [{}]
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [messaging.kafka.receivers.KafkaReceiver.onMessage] after exception: exceptions.MyException: Out of anger
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute    : Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on exceptions.MyException: Out of anger
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute    : Winning rollback rule is: null
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute    : No relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
[ consumer-0-C-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitResourceHolder@2655e199] for key [CachingConnectionFactory [channelCacheSize=25, host=localhost, port=5672, active=true rabbitConnectionFactory]] from thread [consumer-0-C-1]
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Initiating transaction rollback
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   : abortTransaction: CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@b70782d, txId=tran-id-1-acquiring-tms-transaction-consumers.pos_txn_log.0]
[ consumer-0-C-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Clearing transaction synchronization
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.a.r.connection.RabbitResourceHolder  : Rolling back messages to channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,4), conn: Proxy@3c964873 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@5d9ccad2 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 64338]
[ consumer-0-C-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaResourceHolder@23b172f4] for key [org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory@4df8f4e9] from thread [consumer-0-C-1]
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Resuming suspended transaction after completion of inner transaction
[ consumer-0-C-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Initializing transaction synchronization
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Setting JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(23309560<open>)] rollback-only
[ consumer-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Error handler threw an exception
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way Kafka transactions work. Published records are always written to the log, followed by a marker record that indicates whether the transaction committed, or rolled back.

To avoid seeing the rolled-back records, you have to set the consumer `isolation.level` property to `read_committed` (it is `read_uncommitted` by default).

**EDIT**

It's because you are starting a new transaction:

```
template.executeInTransaction(kt -> kt.send(record));
```

```java
/**
 * Execute some arbitrary operation(s) on the operations and return the result.
 * The operations are invoked within a local transaction and do not participate
 * in a global transaction (if present).
 * @param callback the callback.
 * @param <T> the result type.
 * @return the result.
 * @since 1.1
 */
@Nullable
<T> T executeInTransaction(OperationsCallback<K, V, T> callback);
```

Just call `template.send()` and the template will participate in the transaction started by the container.

You can also remove the `@Transactional` from that method.

**EDIT2**

This works as expected for me...

```
spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix=tx-

spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.isolation-level=read-committed

logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=trace
logging.level.org.springframework.kafka.core=trace
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class So66306109Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So66306109Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    Foo foo;

    @Transactional
    @KafkaListener(id = "so66306109", topics = "so66306109") // Not really needed; the container has already started it
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        this.foo.send(in.toUpperCase());
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }


    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so66306109").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so66306109-2").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }


    @KafkaListener(id = "so66306109-2", topics = "so66306109-2")
    public void listen2(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}

@Component
class Foo {

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    @Transactional // Not needed - we're already in a transaction
    void send(String in) {
        this.template.send("so66306109-2", in);
    }

}
```

**EDIT3**

If you cannot upgrade to a supported version, you need to disable transactions in the container, and manage it yourself in your code, within the retry execute scope.

Here is an example.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class So66306109Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So66306109Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    Foo foo;

    @Autowired
    RetryTemplate template;

    @KafkaListener(id = "so66306109", topics = "so66306109") // Not really needed; the container has already started it
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, String> in) {
        this.template.execute(context -> {
            System.out.println(in);
            this.foo.send(in);
            return null;
        }, context -> {
            System.out.println("RETRIES EXHAUSTED");
            return null;
        });
    }


    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so66306109").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so66306109-2").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so66306109-2", topics = "so66306109-2")
    public void listen2(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<String, String> chainedTm(KafkaTransactionManager<String, String> ktm,
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> factory) {

        // transactions can't be started by the container
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(null);
        return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<>(ktm);
    }

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate template() {
        return new RetryTemplate();
    }

}

@Component
class Foo {

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    @Autowired
    ProducerFactory<String, String> pf;

    @Transactional("chainedTm")
    public void send(ConsumerRecord<String,String> in) {
        // updateDB
        this.template.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("so66306109-2", null, null, in.value().toUpperCase()));
        this.template.sendOffsetsToTransaction(Collections.singletonMap(new TopicPartition(in.topic(), in.partition()),
                new OffsetAndMetadata(in.offset() + 1)));

        // simulate a DB rollback
        KafkaResourceHolder<String, String> resource = (KafkaResourceHolder<String, String>) TransactionSynchronizationManager
                .getResource(this.pf);
        resource.setRollbackOnly();
    }

}
```

Note; you must NOT manually acknowledge such records; instead, send the offset to the transaction before it is committed.

Comment: I already have the producer and consumer isolation level set to read_committed. Pls see my config in my last edit.

Comment: It's because you are starting a new transaction - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: I have made the changes to use `template.send()` the behaviour remain the same.

Comment: I just tested it again and it works as expected for me. I will add my test to my answer. My IDE prefers `read-committed` to `read_committed` when setting it via the boot property.

Comment: In any case, you should not be doing retries within the Kafka transaction. You should configure your retry requirements into the container's after rollback processor.

Comment: Still the same. I have enabled trace and added the logs from which it looks like it is rolling back as seend on this line ([ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   : abortTransaction: CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@b70782d, txId=tran-id-1-acquiring-tms-transaction-consumers.pos_txn_log.0]), but somehow the message gets sent to the broker. Any pointers to why this may be happening? Also with respect to configuring retry in container, I am using an older version of spring-kafka, how do I set that up in spring-kafka 2.2.x?

Comment: Since you are seeing the `abortTransaction` call, the transaction is definitely rolled back; as I said, the records are always sent and a marker indicating commit or rollback is put in the log. If you are seeing those records on the consumer side, the problem is you don't have `read_committed` for that consumer. 2.2.x is no longer supported. Boot 2.1.x is end of life. The ability to add back off to the rollback processor was added in 2.3. You CAN'T do retries in the listener with this configuration because the transaction is started by the container. The tx needs to start within the `execute`.

Comment: You are correct, the problem is `read_committed`. The correct property is `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.isolation.level: read_committed` NOT  `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.isolation-level: read-committed` . It works now, many thanks.

Comment: Good. But, if a retry is successful, with that configuration, you will get multiple output records because all the sends are done in the same transaction. See my latest edit to start the transaction inside the retry scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229368/discussion-between-lekkie-and-gary-russell).